# RoR, need to create recursive relationships in table associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm very new to rails, and am a little stuck on the logic for this problem.

I have one table (using mysql) of employees, each of them with a `manager_id` key which refers to the employee they report to. So for example the employee with the title of "CEO" with an id of 1, has a manager_id of nil, and the employee with title of "CTO" has a manager_id of 1. So my records look like this

```
id: 1, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Boss", title: "CEO", manager_id: null
id: 2, first_name: "Pat", last_name: "Guy", title: "CTO", manager_id: 1
id: 3, first_name: "John", last_name: "Dude", title: "VP of engineering", manager_id: 2
```

and my JSON structure should look like this

```
    [
    {id: 1, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Boss", title: "CEO", manager_id: null, descendents: [
      {id: 2, first_name: "Pat", last_name: "Guy", title: "CTO", manager_id: 1, descendents: [
        {id: 3, first_name: "John", last_name: "Dude", title: "VP of engineering", manager_id: 2, descendents: [....]}
        ]},
      {..more CEO descendents...}
    ]
```

I'm trying to create a nested JSON structure that starts at CEO, lists all employees that report to them, and each of those employees descendants. I was trying to write a script that creates this but I keep getting infinite recursive calls. This is what I have

```
        #start at some root
        @root = Employee.find_by title: 'CEO'
        #convert to hash table
        @results[0] = @root.attributes
        #add direct_reports key
        @results[0]["direct_reports"] = []

        def getBelow(root=@root)

            @reports = Employee.where("manager_id = ?", @root[:id])

            if @reports.blank?
                return []
            else
                @reports = @reports.map(&:attributes)
                @reports.each do |person|
                    person["direct_reports"] = []
                    getBelow(person)
                end
                @reports = Employee.where("manager_id = ?", @root[:id])
                root["direct_reports"] = @reports
            end

            return @root
        end

        @list = getBelow(@results[0])
```

If I'm passing in each new person object, shouldn't they all eventually end when `@reports.blank?` becomes true?

An alternative I was thinking of was to use table associations inspired by this blog post

https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord

but that seems a little too complicated.

Comment: Have you try to use [closure_tree](https://github.com/ClosureTree/closure_tree) or  [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)? You can get the job done with any of those gems using a tree data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues in the getBelow method

- You are always using @root, instead of using the param (root). So you are always starting again from the 'CEO'.
- You are calling getBelow recursively but you are not using the result.
- You call `@reports = Employee.where("manager_id = ?", @root[:id])` twice.
- You return @root.

As Jorge Najera said, there are gems that handle a tree structure easily. If you want to build it on your own, this is my suggestion:

```
#start at some root
@root = Employee.find_by manager_id: nil

#convert to hash table
@tree = @root.attributes

#add direct_reports key
@tree["direct_reports"] = getBelow(@root)

def getBelow(manager)

  branch = []

  Employee.where("manager_id = ?", manager.id).each do |employee|
    node = employee.attributes
    node["direct_reports"] = getBelow(employee)
    branch << node
  end
  branch

end
```

This was not tested so I think you´ll get some errors, but I believe the idea is fine.

Comment: I just accepted your answer, can you explain what branch << node does, and why "branch" is by itself right after end? I haven't tested this yet but it is going to be in a GET request so I assume I can just pass in any manager id to get any substructure I want.

Comment: `branch << node` adds an element (node) to the array (branch). branch starts as an empty array and adds elements inside the each loop. As the loop calls the getBelow (recursively), the node itself can have many levels (subbranches).  After `end`, branch has all the nodes added inside the loop (and each node can have subnodes added in recursive calls). You can pass any manager_id to start, and replace the @root element.